# Move the first line of a string to the last one

Tags: python, string, transform

I would like to move the first part of a string to the last part of that string.

An example:

```
AAA
BBB
CCC
```

I would like to transform it to:

```
BBB
CCCAAA
```

I have been finding for solutions to this, but I was only able to see `.readline()` that only works for files, not for variables...

Answer (score 0):

something like

```
spam = """AAA
BBB
CCC"""

spam = spam.splitlines()
first = spam.pop(0)
spam[-1] = ''.join((spam[-1],first))
spam = '\n'.join(spam)
print(spam)
```

output

```
BBB
CCCAAA
```

Alternative:

```
spam = """AAA
BBB
CCC"""

spam = spam.splitlines()
spam = spam[1:-1] + [''.join((spam[-1], spam.pop(0)))]
spam = '\n'.join(spam)
print(spam)
```

output:

```
BBB
CCCAAA
```

Answer (score 0):

You can split the lines and then process them.

```
example="AAA\nBBB\nCCC"
str_lst=example.split("\n")
to_end=str_lst.pop(0)
str_lst.append(to_end)
```

Then you can have a list like this

```
['BBB', 'CCC', 'AAA']
```

Just simply print it however you like then.

Comment: that' not what OP desired output is.

Comment: In the long term it can help him manipulate data as lists are easy to manipulate.

Answer (score 0):

First of all remember that in Python **strings are immutable object**, so you cannot "move" part of string.

This is a possible solution:

```py
s='''AAA
BBB
CCC'''

lines = s.split('\n')
s2 = "\n".join(lines[1:]) + lines[0]

print(s2)
#BBB
#CCCAAA
```

Answer (score -1):

given

```
str = """AAA
BBB
CCC"""

split_text = str.split('\n')
first_part = split_text[0]
rest = split_text[1:]
updated = "".join(rest) + first_part
```

output

```
BBBCCCAAA
```

Comment: that' not what OP desired output is.